# How do I set up a server with a realtime kernel?

Tags: server, kernel

I have installed ubuntu server 11.04 on a machine with size 4GB. As, the ubuntu server 11.04 does not support real time kernel by default, I need compile a real time kernel on ubuntu desktop 11.04 which is on my laptop and then transfer the new kernel to the server machine. Here's comes a few questions to accomplish this task:

1. first of all, I need to install a minimal real time kernel(with only wireless driver), for making the kernel support rt, I know I need to get the related rt patch. the main part is how to set up the minimal kernel. You know, I already tried installing a rt kernel several times, but it just failed. After all, I guess it was because I was missing some of the special modules the kernel needs to load at start up. Now, can anyone having the same experience tell me how to do it?
2. As my space in the main machine is only 4GB, and Ubuntu server has already occupied most of its space, I was told to compile the new kernel on another machine n then transfer the image file to the server and then compile it. I don't know how to do this!! I already installed a new kernel on my laptop, but I don't know how I can transfer it to the server, even if I transfer the bzImage, what about the driver modules and other things?

Answer (score 0):

I would:
1)set up a VM of the base install exactly as your server is but with a larger disk
2)get the kernel sources package and build deps
3)merge the ubuntu diff and the patch diff
4)rebuild the deb with a new name
5)move the deb across and install it with whatever package manager(apt/dpkg)

I don't think this is something for which you should copy/paste commands.

EDIT:
The gist of it was make a [Virtual Machine](https://www.virtualbox.org/) that is identical to your server in question but with enough space to build, as in do not install the virtual optimized kernel/guest additions...because I don't think askubuntu is not the place to cover compiling against different kernels/architectures.

Follow the [existing documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile) to build the debs.  It clearly states how and gives you their names.

Comment: 1) well, there's no larger disk, server size is only 4GB. So, I think you mean that I shall install the rt patch on the same kernel version that the server is using. Here's goes two options: either I can install it on another machine n then transfer the image there (I don't know how) or install the new kernel on server provided that I remove the current non-rt kernel installed on the server.

Comment: 2) please be more accurate, your comment looks ambiguous to me.

Comment: I think you should re-read the answer.  VM == Virtual machine.  Roll a deb means make it a new single file based on the ubuntu deb from repo so it's EASY to copy across and doesn't break the package manger.